# WPF, unable to change canvas height and width from another dialog window; I was making ID card Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to accomplish a new project window where user clicks "new project" a custom dialog appears and accepts width and height input, then after clicking next, it will change the first windows canvas size based on the dialog input
Here is what I tried:
**in the Main Window**

```
// opens up a new file dialog box
        private void StartNewProject()
        {
              New_File newFileDiaBox = new New_File();
              newFileDiaBox.Show();
        }
       
        private void New_file_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          //   calls a new file dialog box method with a new thread
            Thread startNewFileWindow = new Thread(StartNewProject);
            startNewFileWindow.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            startNewFileWindow.Start();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
           
        }
        // Gets the data from dialog window
        internal void GetNewFileData(double W, double H )
            {

                
                Working_card.Width = W;
                Working_card.Height = H;
                MessageBox.Show( "inside the method: "+Working_card.Height.ToString());
            }
**In the New Project dialog window**

   New_Project_Handler NPH = new New_Project_Handler();
        private void SizeChecker()
        {
           
            if (Standard_sizes.IsChecked == true)
            {
                if (CR80.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    NPH.Width_ = 3.375;
                    NPH.Height_ = 2.125;
                }
                else if (CR79.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    NPH.Width_ = 3.303;
                    NPH.Height_ = 2.051;
                }
                else if (Xtended.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    NPH.Width_ = 4.3;
                    NPH.Height_ = 2.125;
                }
                else
                {
                    NPH.Width_ = 3.88;
                    NPH.Height_ = 2.63;
                }

            }
            else if(Custom_sizes.IsChecked==true)
            {
                NPH.Width_ = double.Parse(Width_Value.Text);
                NPH.Height_ = 
                double.Parse(Height_Value.Text);
            }
        MainWindow MainW = new MainWindow();
              
               //press finish btn
               // Call size Checker 
        SizeChecker(); // this is a size checking method
        MainW.GetNewFileData( NPH.Width_,NPH.Height_);
```

Window Preview:
[image: Window Preview]

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread?

Comment: Your posted code does not really provide enough context to review it. Have you used the debugger to check if the correct method is actually called and that the canvas' size is changed to the correct values? I don't think you need the new STA thread to show the dialog. This is not a good idea and does not have any benefit. You should remove the thread creation and run the dialog from the main thread. Maybe this will also fix your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private void New_file_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
  // this is the new file create click function which raises new dialog event .
  // here is the important thing, instead of just calling ShowDialog method on 
  // the dialog window object 
  // we put it in the if() condition as shown below.
  // so if show dialog is true it will get the values and assign them on the   
  // main window. "working_card" is the name of xaml canvas entity on the GUI.
            New_File newF = new New_File(); // object of dialog window creation 
            if (newF.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Working_card.Width = newF.Get_canvasWidth();
                Working_card.Height = newF.Get_canvasHeight();
                Working_card_back.Width = newF.Get_canvasWidth();
                Working_card_back.Height = newF.Get_canvasHeight();
                canvas_Orientation = newF.Get_canvasOrientation();
                if (newF.GetCanavasSides() == true)
                {
                    Back_side_option.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else if (newF.GetCanavasSides() == false)
                {
                    Back_side_option.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
           
        }
```

---

on the other dialog window we have:

---

```
 public partial class New_File : Window
    {
      //  New_Project_Handler nfs = new New_Project_Handler();
   
        public New_File()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       // fields
        private double canvasWidth = 0;
        private double canvasHeight = 0;
        private string canvasOrientation = "";
        private  int next_clk_counter=0;
        private bool side_check = true;
      // properties for the above fields
        public double CanvasWidth
        {
            get { return canvasWidth; }
            set { canvasWidth = value; }
        }

        public double CanvasHeight
        {
            get { return canvasHeight; }
            set { canvasHeight = value; }
        }
        public string CanvasOrientation
        {
            get { return canvasOrientation; }
            set { canvasOrientation = value; }
        }
        public bool Side_check
        {
            get { return side_check; }
            set { side_check = value; }
        }
       // size checker method from the radio buttons received from the dialog
        public void SizeChecker()
        {
           
            if (Standard_sizes.IsChecked == true)
            {
                if (CR80.IsChecked == true)
                {
                  CanvasWidth = 3.375;
                  CanvasHeight = 2.125;
                }
                else if (CR79.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    CanvasWidth = 3.303;
                    CanvasHeight = 2.051;
                }
                else if (Xtended.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    CanvasWidth = 4.3;
                    CanvasHeight = 2.125;
                }
                else
                {
                    CanvasWidth = 3.88;
                    CanvasHeight = 2.63;
                }

            }
            else if(Custom_sizes.IsChecked==true)
            {
                CanvasWidth = double.Parse(Width_Value.Text);
                CanvasHeight = double.Parse(Height_Value.Text);
            }

        
}
  // orientation method from the radio buttons received from the dialog
        public void Canvas_Orientation_Setter()
        { 
             if(Vertical_O.IsChecked==true)
             {
                 double temp_val = CanvasWidth;
                 CanvasWidth = CanvasHeight;
                 CanvasHeight = temp_val;
                
                 CanvasOrientation="Vertical";
             }
             else if (Horizontal_O.IsChecked == true)
             {
                 CanvasOrientation = "Horizontal";
             }
        }
   // whether ID card is double or single sided setter method
        public void ID_side_check()
        { 
            if(Only_front_side.IsChecked== true)
            {
                Side_check= false;
            }
            else if (Both_sides.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Side_check= true;
            }
            
        }
        // get the processed values from the above properties
       // this methods will be called on the main window as shown on the above.
        public double Get_canvasWidth()
        {
             
            return CanvasWidth;
        }
        public double Get_canvasHeight()
        {
            return CanvasHeight;
        }
        public string Get_canvasOrientation()
        {
            return CanvasOrientation;
        }
        public bool GetCanavasSides()
        {
            return Side_check;
        }
     // this is to process that the dialog has 3 states the first page, next and 
    // last which is "finish" button to submit the final values 
        private void First_NextClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (next_clk_counter == 1)
            {
                SizeChecker();
                Canvas_Orientation_Setter();
                ID_side_check();
                MessageBox.Show("The result:" + Get_canvasOrientation() + Get_canvasHeight() + "and " + Get_canvasWidth());
                this.DialogResult = true; 
                
            }
            else
            {
                next_clk_counter = 1;

                back_btn.IsEnabled = true;
                next_btn.Content = "Finish";
                New_File__First_Page.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                New_File__Second_Page.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
           
                
        }

        private void Back_BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (next_clk_counter ==1 )
            {
                next_clk_counter = 0;
                back_btn.IsEnabled = false;
                next_btn.Content = "Next";
                New_File__First_Page.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                New_File__Second_Page.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        private void Standard_sizes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Standard_sizes_options.IsEnabled = true;
            Custom_sizes_options.IsEnabled = false;
            Width_Value.IsEnabled = false;
            Height_Value.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        private void Custom_sizes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Standard_sizes_options.IsEnabled = false;
            Custom_sizes_options.IsEnabled = true;
        }
       

        

    }
}
```

---

So to recap: I have shown you the explanation on the above code; on the submit or "finish" button |in this case| on  the dialog window we add "**this.DialogResult = true;** " this will help to receive any values passed from the dialog and closes the dialog.
I have used properties and methods to get the values from the dialog window and assign for the main window. the above code explain that.